# ^S in terminal does not get sent to Vim

Tags: unix, terminal, shell

I'd like to overload both Ctrl+S and Cmd+S to save a file if I happen to be editing something in Vim.

After some head-scratching I think I've discovered that `^S` in a terminal is perhaps being caught by the shell for sending a signal to the process, or perhaps Vim is doing something special to not listen to it. I have a perl script that puts the term in raw mode which can read my mappings just fine (the `^S` sends hex `0x13`), but nothing happens when I am in Vim `Ctrl+V` verbatim-mode and type it. In the bare zsh shell, verbatim-mode does show me that I am pressing `^S`. This seems to refute the proposition that there is some terminal program flow-control bound to this key, as I am able to get zsh to see it.

How can I get vim to recognize my Ctrl+S?

Answer (score 2):

`^S` is the ASCII XOFF character. Together with XON (`^Q`), they are the two control signals used for [software flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control).

They are not intercepted by the shell, but by the terminal, which intercepts `^S` to mean halt terminal output and `^Q` to mean resume it.

You can configure your terminal (using `stty -ixon -ixoff`) to ignore them by turning off software flow control, but it may be futile: it's ill-advised to attempt to assign other functions to XON and XOFF because there might be something else in the user's session (a remote terminal, a modem, some other piece of RS-232 equipment) that interprets them.

Answer (score 1):

`stty -ixon` (and `stty -ixoff` for good measure) did it for Terminal.app, iTerm2.